# Update column with more than one value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table **tableA** which looks something like this:

```
issue_id   start_date   end_date     
issue1     2019-11-07   2020-04-30  
issue2     2019-11-07   2020-01-28
```

I have to update the end_date based on the results of the query.

```
UPDATE tableA SET end_date = 
(

SELECT max_end_date from update_end_date

)
WHERE issue_id = (SELECT issue_id FROM update_end_date);
```

It works when when query returns one result. However it fails when more than one results are returned which make sense. I cannot pre determine the results of the query so it might return more than one result. Is there any way if I can update the column with multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET end_date = (SELECT max_end_date 
                from update_end_date 
                WHERE update_end_date.issue_id = tableA.issue_id)
WHERE issue_id IN (SELECT issue_id FROM update_end_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to @Lukas solution is using [proprietary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) PostgreSQL's syntax `UPDATE FROM`

```
UPDATE tablea
   SET end_date = max_end_date
  FROM update_end_date
 WHERE tablea.issue_id = update_end_date.issue_id
```